# Webpack is not importing reflect-metadata properly with chunking

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, commonjs, webpack-splitchunks, reflect-metadata

recently I've been trying to convert my aws-lambda project from outputting cjs to esm.  The only thing left that doesn't work is my usage of reflect-metadata.  In this project I also do chunking:

```
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                defaultVendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    filename: 'vendors-[name].js',
                    priority: -10,
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I'm importing reflect metadata like this:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

When I had cjs before, I can see this call

```
// EXTERNAL MODULE: ../../../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
var reflect_metadata_Reflect = __webpack_require__(48060);
```

After outputting esm (it works when I remove reflect-metadata), I see this err

```
 "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')",
        "    at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)"
```

I know for sure this is dying at the import line, since I put console.logs before and after it.

The main difference I see is that now the webpack_require for reflect-metadatacall is now

```
__webpack_require__(8060);
```

When I remove chunking and everything is in one file it works.  I'm guessing that somehow this webpack_require doesn't actually import require-metadata properly.  I did try doing something like `import * as asdf from 'reflect-metadata'` but no luck

Does anyone have any advice or tips to try?